# Interface to return Generic type

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have an interface that returns a Connection. I've changed to Object, because I need to return sometimes a Connection and sometimes a MongoDatabase object from Mongo.
My poor ideia was to change this method to Object, like this:

`Object getConnnection(String uri);`

Is a poor design? Any suggestion to improve this aproach? Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Comment: How are you going to use the interface in your code? Are you going to check every time if the returned Object is Mongo or JDBC? Once you answer that question, it should be easier to decide how to change the interface, and even if it should be an interface with two implementations, or separate entirely..

Comment: In what context would this interface be implemented?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Factory pattern does not solve this issue. Factory pattern is a creational design pattern. It solves problems related to instantiation. This problem is about the return type of a method that appears to be random and involves totally unrelated types.

Comment: Please provide more context if you want serious help. It's not clear what you are doing and ow the interface is used and how the implementation looks like.

Comment: @Jorn yes. My goal is to design an API, and all the time the foreign applications will use different databases. The MongoDB wiil be used for "caching" some results for the user, and Mysql will act as repository.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an interface that returns a Connection. I've changed to Object,
> because I need to return sometimes a Connection and sometimes a
> MongoDatabase object from Mongo. My poor ideia was to change this
> method to Object, like this:
>
> ```
> Object getConnnection(String uri);
> ```
>
> Is a poor design?

If the intended uses of this interface will require users to cast the return value, or otherwise do anything with it that depends on knowing or assuming whether it is a `Connection` or a `MongoDatabase`, then yes, it is a poor design.

Also, `getConnection` is a terrible name for a method that in fact might return something that is not a `Connection`.

> Any suggestion to improve this aproach?

There are plenty of alternatives that would be better, but which one is best for you depends on how you want to use instances of this interface.  Some of the more likely possibilities are

- give the interface separate methods for retrieving a `Connection` and for retrieving a `MongoDatabase`.  This is not great if individual instances cannot be expected to be able to do both, but even then it's better than the version presented in the question.
- provide a separate interface representing objects that can provide `MongoDatabase`s, with an appropriately-named method for that purpose.
- put a method for retrieving a `MongoDatabase` (only) on a class implementing the interface, and make methods that need to be able to exercise that `getMongoDatabase()` method require instances specifically of that class.  Possibly create a sub-interface that specifies the `getMongoDatabase()` method.
- make the interface generic, parameterized by the type of object to which it provides access.  For example,

  ```
  interface DatabaseAccessor<T> {
      public T getDatabaseObject();
  }
  ```

  Each implementation would then be specific for `Connection`s or `MongoDatabase`s or some other similar thing.  Other methods that want to consume these specify what flavor of `DatabaseAccessor` they need via the type parameter.

Comment: thanks a lot. The last solution with Generic Type works for me. I will have queries for some classes that consult the api. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you plan to only use `toString` or the other few methods available on `Object`, that type isn't useful. Thus, client code will have to attempt to downcast in order to do something more useful with it. Thus, it's generally regarded as a design smell. I don't currently have my copy of [Refactoring](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/refactoring) handy, but as far as I recall, it describes the code smell and suggests better alternatives.

What's a better design? This depends on context. Why does the interface exist in the first place?

You may consider following the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), which entails that abstractions should be defined by client code, and not by the implementing class.

Since you don't describe the needs of client code, it's difficult to suggest a better API. I'd suggest to look at the requirements that client code has, and then define a type (interface or base class) that supports those interactions. Then return that type from the method.

If you can't do that, a [sum type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) could be useful. Unfortunately, most object-oriented languages don't support sum types natively, but you [can implement them with the Visitor design pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/25/visitor-as-a-sum-type).

Comment: Your interpretation of the Dependency Inversion principle is wrong. Also the interface is not the problem. The problem is that a method and potentially the class has too many responsibilities, that's obvious by the fact that the same method returns totally unrelated objects. Even worse, the caller does not seem to have any influence on the returned value. So recommending the Single Responsibility principle might be more adequate and helpful.

Comment: Dependency inversion does not help because he already has created an interface to invert the dependency. The problem is how this interface is implemented. It's a good example why declaring interface member and parameter types of type object. It does not add any robustness nor does it put any constraint on the final implementation in order to guarantee that the implementation fulfills the purpose/contract.

Comment: @BionicCode *"Your interpretation of the Dependency Inversion principle is wrong."* Would you care to elaborate on why that is the case?

Comment: @BionicCode "Your interpretation of the Dependency Inversion principle is wrong." :-D. That's funny that you're saying this to a man who wrote three books ([1](https://manning.com/seemann), [2](https://blog.ploeh.dk/dippp), [3](https://blog.ploeh.dk/code-that-fits-in-your-head)) on software design principles and patterns and created [Pluralsight courses](https://blog.ploeh.dk/encapsulation-and-solid) on SOLID design principles.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Sure. I found your summary of the DIP *"that abstractions should be defined by client code, and not by the implementing class."* wrong in that it does not reflect the original intent or meaning. In my understanding where there is "client code" then the client code is the context that provides the implementation to the abstraction (usually defined by a library, framework or component). However, I still find your terminology of "client code" vs "implementing class" very irritating in this context. Maybe you meant that he should have created the abstraction before the implementation.

Comment: @Steven Even when a person had written 20 books this doesn't mean that this person can't make mistakes, misunderstand or express himself wrong or not precise. In my understanding there is no relationship or correlation between the number of published books and the number or severity of mistakes a person can make. And anybody can point out such errors. This is how science works.  
Anyway, thanks for enriching the discussion by pointing out his achievements ;-)

Comment: @BionicCode. I was paraphrasing [APPP, chapter 11](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/appp): *"clients [...] own the abstract interfaces"*, and I believe that my use of *client code* is congruent with that, but yes, the implication is that one should create the abstraction before the implementation. Furthermore, the abstraction should be driven by the needs of client code, and not by the implementation details of the implementing class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for the reference. Now I know what you mean. I even know this book. And I have a strong opinion on the offered ownership interpretation. I believe Robert C. Martin fully agrees with me by later revoking his statement (or to be more precise, by limiting his special interpretation to a very limited case).

Comment: The ownership of the abstractions is not a pure philosophical question as implied. On class level the ownership doesn't really matter, indeed. It doesn't change the class level dependency graph whether I announce either the client or the server as the owner. But on component level it actually does matter. It really makes a difference. This is where the author revokes his statement I guess.

Comment: The point is that when defining the abstraction in the client's component (the component that uses the abstraction) the server (the component that serves the implementation/functionality) has now a dependency on the client. On component level we use DIP to implement IoC. We do this do revert this exact dependency: we want that the client depends on the server. We want that the client code depends on the framework. We don't want our framework to depend on the client. We don't want our business layer to depend on the UI layer. We want the opposite.

Comment: This means we invert the dependencies (like DIP requires) but we do not invert ownership. This is a very important detail. As provoking his philosophical view is, it is not always the right or always applicable. While it may work on class level, it usually doesn't work on application level. Now that we are clear about the original definition, I still believe that your are not correct here.

Comment: The idea of ownership inversion is a philosophical point of view introduced by Robert C. Martin. It is definitely not part of the DIP (which was also postulated by Robert C. Martin). To say that *"entails that abstractions should be defined by client code, and not by the implementing class"* is  just wrong, because there is no such entailment or implication in the DIP postulation. And you are not "paraphrasing" correctly. Because his idea in regard of ownership inversion is not about the *"definition"* of abstractions but their ownership.

Comment: I hope you agree that the business layer defines the interfaces based on the application's functionality. The business layer is the reusable part of the application and not the user interface. The framework or library defines the API and not the client. .NET is written *before* the client code. This fact makes your suggestion "wrong" too: *"I'd suggest to look at the requirements that client code has, and then define a type (interface or base class) that supports those interactions."*.

Comment: You provide the interface to abstract away persistence layer so that the client can use it without knowledge of any details. In other words you pick the database or services your application is based on. Then you design the API/abstractions that allow the client to use it. Because you start your design with use cases, you know what functionality the client must use in order to satisfy the use cases or to provide the required data input in order to allow the business logic to satisfy the use cases.

Comment: Your suggestion to me reads like you have to design and implement client code first before you implement the server. Of course, he (the OP) should have designed the abstractions before the implementation in order to implement the dependencies properly (in terms of DIP). We want our code to depend on abstractions, so we must abstract away the functionality before we implement it. He should have started with defining the use cases or user stories in order to derive the required functionality and abstractions.

Comment: For example: "User saves username". Then in the next step, he designs the abstract server API for example the `public abstract void SaveUser(username: string) : void` to allow the client to save the username. In the next step the client then designs his code around this abstraction that the server implements.

Comment: Now *"Furthermore, the abstraction should be driven by the needs of client code, and not by the implementation details of the implementing class.*" turns out to not precise too, because client code never depends on implementation details but on abstractions - and *that* is the meaning of DIP. that's why abstractions are introduced in the context of DIP. The client has to use implementation details. To decouple this relationship we introduce the interface, that of course are an abstraction of this low-level details.

Comment: Again, your referenced statement is about ownership and not dependency. Dependencies are already inverted. The correct phrasing would be that "abstractions should be driven by the abstract low-level functionality of the server (the implementing class) like a framework defines the abstractions by the input required to do the work. Because those abstractions define the interface of client and server. To me this difference is important because you usually design complex applications and not a handful of lose classes.

Comment: The structure of the applications dictates the ownership of the interfaces. For example when implementing the IoC pattern the ownership must be with the server (e.g. a framework). Client code always complements server code. From that point of view it doesn't make sense to allow the client to define interfaces and then let the server implement them. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Because the server is the constant that usually does not change. The classic client-server relationship is a many-to-one: many clients use a single server. In other words, many different complementing potentially unrelated client implementations use the same interface or abstraction layer to use the functionality of the server (where the server is either a class, component, application, library or framework).

Comment: Just another note, Robert C. Martin even considers a third valid owner relationship: no owner. So we have abstraction ownership is inverted too and owned by the client, the non-inverted classic view where abstractions are owned by the server and another classic where the abstractions are neither owned by the client nor the server (standalone).